# How to use !-1 in javascript switch-case function

Tags: javascript

I "want" to use switch, but i can't seem to get it to work when I use it in this fashion. Anyone know why?

```
var mystring='my name is johnny';  
switch (!-1) {  
          case mystring.indexOf('hello'):  
        alert('hello');  
        break;  
    case mystring.indexOf('goodbye'):  
        alert('goodbye');  
        break;  
    case mystring.indexOf('johnny'):  
        alert('johnny');  
        break;  
    default:  
        alert('default');           
}
```

it always alerts "default", but you can see that I want it to alert "johnny"

Comment: If you want to use `indexOf` in a 'switch'; the best you can do is chain a bunch of `if` and `else if(s)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** This switch is *evil*. Use if/else-if statements. but if you must use a switch it can be done as such:

```
switch (true) {  
    case /hello/.test(mystring):  
        alert('hello');  
        break;  
    case /goodbye/.test(mystring):  
        alert('goodbye');  
        break;  
    case /johnny/.test(mystring):  
        alert('johnny');  
        break;  
    default:  
        alert('default');           
}
```

Should work as you want it to.

[`.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

I would be tempted to refactor it further.

```
function Parse(str) {
    var logic = {
        "hello": function(str) { alert("hello"); }
        /*, ... */
    }

    for (var k in logic) {
        if ((new RegExp(k)).test(str)) {
            logic[k](str);
        }
    }
}

Parse("Hello I am johnny");
```

Comment: the first worked, i will use that one. thank you.   the second looks like it works also, but harder to read.  the problem i have had has been reading my code.

Comment: This is a _really_ bastardized `switch` statement. It can be done so much more clearly and succinctly using `if`/`else if` (though I do understand that you're simply _demonstrating how_ to do it with a `switch`).

Comment: Read this amazing article and avoid switch-case syndrome - http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/how-to-avoid-switch-case-syndrome/

Answer (score 6):

`!-1` coerces `-1` to a boolean, and then negates it, so

```
switch(!-1)
{
    // stuff
}
```

is equivalent to

```
switch(false)
{
    // stuff
}
```

Since there is no `case false`, the `default` will always be executed. This is **really** not the right way to use a switch — there is no point in `switch`ing on a constant expression.

Why do you "want" to use a `switch`?

---

Here's how to implement it correctly:

```
var mystring='my name is johnny';

if (mystring.indexOf('hello') !== -1) alert('hello');
else if (mystring.indexOf('goodbye') !== -1) alert('goodbye');
else if (mystring.indexOf('johnny') !== -1) alert('johnny');
```

Or, less repetetively,

```
var mystring='my name is johnny',
    words = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'johnny'],
    word;

while (word = words.shift(), mystring.indexOf(word) === -1);

word = word || 'default';
alert(word);
```

Comment: He knows that if it is not found it returns -1. So he's trying to switch on the one that returns 0 or more. Except the negation of `-1` returns a boolean so that doesn't help. There is some (perverse) logic in this. The best solution would be to switch on a real boolean and replace `indexOf` with a regular expression `.test` statement.

Comment: I understand what he's trying to do. The implementation is completely bass-ackwards, though.

Comment: when i run the code using -1 instead of !-1  it seems to run ok.  I am rewriting a function I used to parse html results. I was using if-then-elseif before. I may just need to return to that

Comment: @Chester **please** don't tell me you're using `indexOf` to parse HTML. You should be using the DOM.

Comment: @matt, i cant use the dom because i get the html using ajax in one tab, then pass it to another tab using chrome.sendmessage

Comment: @Chester are you parsing the text in the first tab, or the second tab?

Comment: i parse it in the second tab, but regardless of which tab i parse it in the results come from an ajax $get function and there is no DOM.

Comment: @ChesterCopperpot create anew DOMFragment with the HTML. `var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();fragment.innerHTML = html;`

Comment: @Chester @Raynos it sounds like you're using jQuery, in which case `$(text)` will do all the work.

Comment: Raynos, i never knew of the fragment function.  i will play with that. sounds quite useful. 
matt,  not sure how u mean to implement $(text)

Comment: @Chester, are you using jQuery? If so: say the HTML string returned from the ajax call is stored in a variable named `html` (just like in Raynos' comment). Then `$(html)` returns a jQuery object which contains the parsed input HTML tree.

Comment: matt, i can then edit the dom with that?

var mydiv=$(html).('#div_id');

Comment: @Chester yes you can, but not quite like that. Try `var mydiv = $(html).find('#div_id');`

Answer (score 3):

Your combination of "not"(`!`) and "`-1`" seems faulty. You need to move them to your cases like this

```
var mystring='my name is johnny';  
switch (true) {  
          case mystring.indexOf('hello') != -1:  
        alert('hello');  
        break;  
    case mystring.indexOf('goodbye') != -1:  
        alert('goodbye');  
        break;  
    case mystring.indexOf('johnny') != -1:  
        alert('johnny');  
        break;  
    default:  
        alert('default');           
}
```

It's a pain in PHP that `strpos(...)` returns `false` when not found and `0` when string starts with it (and those 2 values are `==`, but not `===`) but I personally find JavaScripts `indexOf(..) == -1` even worse. (Why can't it be `false` or `null`?)

Comment: PHP is open source -> rewrite the relevant extension

Comment: @Matt Ball I am aware of this thread...it was partly a cynical response and partly a sad one, as it seems I'll have to do something on those lines... (besides, I am not one of the maintainers)

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is you're `switch`ing the result of `!-1` and that `case` isn't found. `switch-case` doesn't seem to be the right construct to use here.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `!-1` will just evaluate to `false`.

You are trying to convert a comparison like `x != -1` into `x == !-1`, but the `!` operator doesn't negate the comparison, only the value.

Comment: condition evaluates, Always, to a value (boolean)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your implementation is correct. The proper conditional statement to use is **if... else**.

> var mystring='my name is johnny';
>
> if(mystring.indexOf('hello') != -1)
> alert('hello');
>
> else if(mystring.indexOf('goodbye') !=
> -1) alert('goodbye'); 
> else if(mystring.indexOf('johnny') !=
> -1) alert('johnny'); 
> else alert('default');

Answer (score -2):

The switch should be mystring, example:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: -1 For w3schools reference. W3Schools is not a reliable source of information. Follow the [campaign](http://w3fools.com/). The MDN would be a far better resource for [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: @Guffa you can log into the MDC page and edit/fix the error yourself. For errors in the w3schools page you can email them, I doubt they will fix them (There are plenty of other errors they don't fix)

Comment: @Raynos: No, the campaign page.

Comment: @Guffa the w3fools page has a list of `FROM:" right at the top with a bunch of twitter accounts. tweet one of them to get in touch.